# Cordovarduino not working

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm using cordovarduino with phonegap to connect an arduino via OTG to a android app built using phonegap. I programmed an arduino to send data (working and verified on terminal), but when I connect it to the phone then it doesn't give any output.

Am I missing something , like allowing a permission or so?
The git used by me for reference : https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem using console.log and other console output. The problem was I hadn't added the plugin to the config file. Doind

```
phonegap plugin add cordovarduino
```

& re-building solved the issue